# Putting one SQL table on top of another using oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

This is probably a very simple question but I cannot find the solution. I have two tables with identical column names and I wish to put one on top of the other. I have tried UNION but this appears not to work and I get the error 'ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression'

I am using Oracle SQL Developer to access the data.

table1 =

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111111 | 2222222 | 3333333 |
| aaaaaaa | bbbbbbb | ccccccc |

table2 =

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9999999 | 8888888 | 7777777 |
| zzzzzzz | yyyyyyy | xxxxxxx |

desired output

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111111 | 2222222 | 3333333 |
| aaaaaaa | bbbbbbb | ccccccc |
| 9999999 | 8888888 | 7777777 |
| zzzzzzz | yyyyyyy | xxxxxxx |

I have tried the following script to get it - any assistance would be appreciated.

```
select * from table1
union
select * from table2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type problem might be fixed by explicitly listing out all columns in the select clause.  In addition, you should introduce a computed column which maintains the order of the two halves of the union in the output.

```sql
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM
(
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, 1 AS src
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column1, column2, column3, 2
    FROM table2
) t
ORDER BY src;
```